# rails 3.1 engines and databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Can rails 3.1 engines have their own databases and at the same time also have access to the database of the main app, for example for user authentication
How can i configure this if possible?

thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on your question? what do you mean by "the main app"?

Comment: I mean the app where i attach the engines to

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they can. I have built engines that use a separate sqlite3 database. This way all the engine's functionality and data is isolated. Remove the engine, remove the database, and everything is gone without leaving a trace.

First of all it's preferred that you generate a [mountable engine](http://www.spacebabies.nl/2012/07/06/rails-engine-mountable-or-not/). This creates a namespace and isolates the engine from your main app. It's not a requirement, but a best practice. I assume you've done in the examples that follow.

At one point you are going to generate a model inside your engine. In the engine root path, type something like this:

```
$ rails generate resource Post
```

This will generate the Post controller, model and route. Everything's perfect except for the database migration. You're going to delete this. This migration is useless if you want to keep your data separate. The only goal of migrations inside engines is to have them copied over to the main app's database. So go ahead and get rid of it:

```
$ rm -r db
```

Now hook up your root route and controller, like usual.

There's one more change to make inside the model, to make it connect to a separate database.

```
module YourEngine
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => 'db/your_engine.sqlite3'
  end
end
```

This way the engine's model will not use the main database, but the one you define. The key to understand is that the database file does **not** live inside the engine! This database file lives inside the host application. Since you are keeping everything separate, you must create this database by hand. Using the sqlite3 command-line tool and a hand-crafted create statement is quickest:

```
$ cd "the root dir of the host rails app"
$ sqlite3 db/your_engine.sqlite3
```

from where you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE your_engine_posts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', body text, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL);
```

Presto! Now it's just a matter of mounting the engine inside your app, boot it and it should all be ready to roll. Obviously now that your engine has a separate database, it's no use working with migrations. You will have to update the schema by hand.

Comment: What if I am using mysql2 and not sqlite? In your example, you create schema in host application using: sqlite3 db/your_engine.sqlite3. What would you do in the case of mysql2?

Comment: In that case you could consider writing the migrations inside the engine and running the migrations inside the engine folder. I did not try this.

Comment: I mean can I have a database.yml for the engine?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about table names clashing with the app you can use the 'isolate_namespace' method. This will prefix all your table names with the namespace of your Engine.

Rails Casts just had a good tutorial which uses this, you should check it out.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can.
I wrote a guide on this here
http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=42143